# Applicative functor in F*: Type checking error

Tags: applicative, fstar

As an experiment while trying to get familiar with F*, I tried implementing an applicative functor. I'm stuck at a weird-looking type checking error. I'm not sure yet if this is due to some feature / logic in the type checking that I'm not aware of, or if this is caused by a genuine bug.

Here is the part of the code that is causing me trouble :

```
module Test

noeq type test : Type -> Type =
    | Apply : test ('a -> 'b) -> test 'a -> test 'b

val apply : test ('a -> 'b) -> test 'a -> test 'b
let apply f x = Apply f x
```

And here is the corresponding error :

```
Test(7,24-7,25): (Error 54) Test.test 'a is not a subtype of the expected type Test.test 'a (see also Test(7,12-7,13))
1 error was reported (see above)
```

Could someone kindly point out to me what I'm missing ? Is the behaviour of type unification affected by subtyping ? Or should this type-check and this is a compiler bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a universe inequality constraint on inductives that you are not enforcing.

The following code will typecheck:

```
noeq type test : Type0 -> Type =
    | Apply : test ('a -> 'b) -> test 'a -> test 'b

val apply : test ('a -> 'b) -> test 'a -> test 'b
let apply f x = Apply f x
```

Notice the `0` I added on the first line.

This works because this states that the first `Type0` is in a lower universe than than `Type` (which itself, I believe, means any universe).
In your case, F* doesn't know how to compare the universes for these two types, hence fails.

If you had written `noeq type test : Type -> Type0` you would have seen a slightly better error message: "Failed to solve universe inequalities for inductives". So I blame the error message here.

I apologize if the explanation lacks precision, I am not a PL person... : )

Comment: Errors of the kind `type t is not a subtype of type t` are often related to Universes. You can typecheck using the flag `--print_universes` for slightly more information.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that since the tutorial doesn't mention universes. Thanks for giving me the compiler flag, it'll sure come in handy :)